# Is there a way to find out what is causing 'No Instance Found' on run in Alloy?

Tags: alloy, formal-languages, formal-verification, formal-methods

I have written in model using Alloy. However for certain conditions running the predicate to find an instance is failing and it says that no instance can be found. I tried increasing the bound to about 16 instances, yet it does not find any instance.

Is there any way I can debug this so that I can see which facts are failing which is causing Alloy not being able to find an instance?

Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

If you change the default sat solver to minisat with unsat core, then it will be possible to highlight the constraints that can't be satisfied in a same instance.

Another possible solution is to comment your constraints one by one until analysis yield an instance hence pinpointing which constraint might cause trouble.

For a more specific answer, please share your model.

Comment: How do I change the SAT solver? Do I select it from the options tab? However for me, it doesn't show any other option apart from SAT4J.

Comment: Yes, other solvers are present as binaries in the jar file. They might not be compatible with the system you are running. I'd thus suggest to try your luck with the second option and if nothing comes out of it, feel free to share your model